# Android issues with eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I installed the Android SDK installer_r20-windows.exe

When I went to install android tools via eclipse, it displays the error:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Android Development Tools 22.0.5.v201307292155--757759 

(com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 22.0.5.v201307292155--757759)
  Missing requirement: Android Development Tools 22.0.5.v201307292155--757759 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 22.0.5.v201307292155--757759)

requires 'org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

What version of eclipse is compatible with android installer_r20-windows.exe?

Comment: have you tried using android studio?

Comment: I'm using classic and it's working great.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem with the Linux version of Eclipse 3.8.
The following solution from [Google FAQ page](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/faq?hl=es&csw=1#wstinstallerror) worked for me, and as it was quite platform independent, it might help at other platforms too:

1) Select Help > Install New Software...

2) Add the update software site (by clicking Add...) and enter http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo [change the last word according to your Eclipse version] for the Location.

3) After adding the update site, try installing Android Developer Tools again, it should download all dependencies now.